# Using JS in Swift to hide WKWebView collection elements

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I have a website that I have loaded into WKWebView. I want to hide the header of this website, so that I can use a native header that I have built in storyboard instead. The header element can only be referred to by class (i.e. "header-layout-bar").

I have been using this code as reference in order to hide the header.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finishload")
    let element = "header-layout-bar"
    let removeElementScript = "var element = document.getElementsByClassName('\(element)'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element); console.log(element);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeElementScript) { (response, error) in
        debugPrint("Am here")
    }
}
```

When I print out element in the console to see whether it has been selected, it prints an empty HTML Collection Array. Removing it this way does not hide it.

I have tried several variations on this theme to no avail (e.g. selecting it using getElementsByTagName).

Nothing works. Can someone provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try hiding it with css:

```
let removeElementScript = "document.querySelector('.header-layout-bar').style.display='none';"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeElementScript) { (response, error) in
    debugPrint("Am here")
}
```